# Нужно ли обособлять "при этом"?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда в четырёх последних поединках выиграл лишь однажды, но, при этом, будешь драться за временный пояс.

Comment: Семантика (и грамматика) предложения неясна. "Если в четырёх последних поединках выиграл лишь однажды, то тогда будешь драться за временный пояс". Или здесь дугой смысл?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужно, это обстоятельство, значит, не вводное, пояснять тоже здесь нечего.